# Estimate good parameters for Algorithms with lots of arguments (Like for MSER in OpenCV)

Tags: algorithm, opencv, parameters, mser

I was wondering if there is a better way to estimate a good set of parameters for algorithms with lots of arguments than just randomly picking them. In detail I am trying to find some good parameters for the MSER Feature Detector which consumes 9 number parameters so there is a huge space to search in. I was thinking about alternatingly picking smaller and larger numbers around the default parameter value with exponentially growing distance. Are there any good thoughts that could help me?

Thanks!

Comment: If you can systematically quantify how "good" the results are when you try a given set of parameters, then there are some high-powered techniques you could use, involving the Jacobian and Hessian matrices of the "goodness" function (which can be estimated by lots of trials even if you don't have a formula for it). Look for scientific computing libraries that try to maximize/minimize multi-valued functions -- finding best-fit curves is an important application, which is why there are common tools for it. But that might be beyond what's reasonable or even possible in your case.

Comment: That sounds very good to me, didn't came up with this ;-) but there is no functional analysis of what is good in that scenario. Sure I could use some geometric verification like RANSAC on matching points but to see if to matching regions on different images are really the same I have to look at them. I guess this is where thous methods fall short.

Comment: For example your quality function could work by running a whole bunch of test cases for which you already know the correct answer, and scoring how many it gets right, and how close. Probably a lot of work to set that up, it will take ages to run, and you could end up with parameters incredibly well-tuned for your test cases but still fails in real use. But you probably want some kind of test set anyway if you're messing with the parameters manually, just to make sure you haven't broken it...

Comment: Hm yes overfitting is a problem thats true. So I think I really need my own testbed and take care of a lot of eventualities....

Answer (score 0):

First, you must define an objective function you want to minimize - what defines "better" parameters? In your case, I'd suggest using the number of correct matches found or similar.

Second, you must have an efficient way of looping over the virtually uncountable possibilities. Here, it probably helps that there is a minimal step size beyond which the results don't meaningfully change. Since the objective function is not necessarily derivable, I'd use a method similar to the [Golden search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_section_search) in each dimension separately, and then repeat, until hopefully a global "good enough" maximum is reached.